# Apache mod_session_crypt crashing server

Tags: apache, session, encryption, session-cookies

using Apache 2.4 on a windows 2008R2 server, I am trying to encrypt my session using the following directive

```
Session On

SessionCookieName session path=/

SessionCryptoPassPhrase secretcode
```

We are using form based authentication.

use of **SessionCryptoPassPhrase** crashes the server. If I dont use that directive it does not encrypt and works fine. Please help if anybody had this issue and found a solution.

I see this error in application event log

```
Faulting application httpd.exe, version : 2.4.12.0, horodatage : 0x5565a671 faulting module libaprutil-1.dll, version : 1.5.4.0 Code exception : 0xc0000005
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution,
In fact [http://www.apachelounge.com](http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=30900#30900) corrected a bug and made a new release which is working great!